# No style.xml in Android-Project

Tags: android

I created a project in Eclipse, worked a lot of in it and changed my IDE to Android-Studio. Now I need to change some things in style.xml and found out, that i did not was generated.
It possible to let it generate now?

PS: I added the library com.android.support:support-v13:22.1.1 to my project.

Comment: Can you post your project structure in the IDE

Comment: `app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml` and `app/java` (with the code) and `app/res/drawable+layout+menu+values`

Answer (score 1):

It could be under themes.xml

Here's a simple styles.xml template with my Activity extending AppCompatActivity

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    </style>
</resources>
```

It's under res->values->styles.xml

Comment: Could you copy the styles.xml from your old project to android studio?

Comment: I have no old project, I just used the same in Android-Studio

Comment: @piet you imported eclipse project to android studio?.

Comment: yes, right, and now I only work in Android Studio. In eclipse the styles.xml wasnt there, too.

Comment: @Piet you should have `styles.xml`. I don't see a problem importing eclipse project to android studio. Just that you will have gradle buildsystem. How did you import the project??

Comment: Again, I never had a style.xml, I think it never was generated in Eclipse. If I would have a style.xml, I think I sould see it in the folder....

Comment: @Piet that is why asked what procedure did you adapt to import the project in android studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84288/discussion-between-piet-and-raghunandan).